# Django: how to group apps in directories?

Tags: django

I am using modified sources from few third party apps in my project. I would like to put these third party apps in a separate directory, so that they are not on the same directory level as my own apps. Is this possible in django?

I tried simply putting the apps in a directory `thirdparty` and changed my `INSTALLED_APPS` like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'my_app',
    ...
    'thirdparty.django_messages',
```

This of course failse with:

```
ImportError: No module named thirdparty
```

After which I naturally added `__init__.py` to the directory. But it fails again:

```
ImportError: No module named django_messages.apps
```

Just to avoid any confusion, the app `django_messages` does contain `apps.py`

Is there a way to group django apps in a directory or do they all have to be in the same project root directory?

### Edit

A better alternative is in the accepted answer by [Antoine Pinsard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529346/antoine-pinsard)

For those persistent on grouping apps see accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862084/how-do-i-create-sub-applications-in-django)!

Comment: Its unclear what you're trying to achieve. [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sayse what is unclear? I ask in the title and in last sentence precisely what I am trying to achieve. I will attempt to make the question clearer.

Comment: What is unclear is *why* you want to do this, what problem are you trying to fix by doing so?

Comment: @Sayse Just organizing a project which contains a lot of apps. Wanted to check if this is possible.

Comment: But you're not achieving anything by doing it, if you really want to, add a comment line above the third party apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't do this.** If you really need to modify the source code of third-party apps, fork the repositories so that you will be able to watch and merge upstream updates.

Then install the modified apps with `pip`.

For instance, if you have forked `django-autocomplete-light` on your github (let's say https://github.com/dsalaj/django-autocomplete-light):

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/dsalaj/django-autocomplete-light.git
```

You will be able to upgrade it like any other pip package:

```
pip install --upgrade git+ssh://git@github.com/dsalaj/django-autocomplete-light.git
```

And even add it to your `requirements.txt`.

---

As [Mad Wombat mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940122/django-how-to-group-apps-in-directories/35940264?noredirect=1#comment59546688_35940264), you can use pip's `--editable` (`-e`) option to install these packages in a specific folder within your project. From `pip help`:

> -e, --editable  Install a project in editable mode (i.e. setuptools "develop mode") from a local project path or a VCS url.

---

Nevertheless, to answer the question. The issue is that the app `django_messages` considers it is a top-level module (and it is supposed to be). Thus it can import its submodules using an absolute python path (starting with `django_messages.`). However, when you place it within a module `thirdparty`, `django_messages` becomes a submodule of `thirdparty`. You could add the `thirdparty` directory to your `PYTHON_PATH` so that `django_messages` is available as a top-level module. But it is really not advisable to do so. `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` is the best place for your third party packages and this is where pip installs them.

You may also be interested in [python virtualenvs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) if you don't know what they are.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it is a good alternative. But could you please answer if it is possible to do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You really don't want to achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: I would be thankful for an elaboration on why this is such a bad idea. Anyway [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862084/how-do-i-create-sub-applications-in-django) is the possible answer to what I was looking.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Comment: Agree with all that Antoine said. But there are actually ways to keep your customized libraries separate from regular pip packages. You can use pip "editable" installs `pip install -e git+ssh://github.com/whatever`. This will install packages into ./src directory in your current dir and will update a .pth file in python site-packages to include it. The other way is to create a custom .pth file and place it manually in site-packages. Both ways have their advantages and disadvantages, too long to list in a comment.