# Best way to structure a Django project

Tags: django, structure

I'm new to django and plan on building a large django project.

I'm starting to implement cookicutter django after reading through "2 Scoops of Django" but still have some questions on structuring a project.

I've setup my project, we'll call it 'business_proj'. In business_proj I started an app called 'accounting' this might have an accounting dashboard for users in the accounting security group. Now, what if I want to have apps that belong to accounting, such as 'invoices' and 'purchase_orders'? Should I create those apps inside my accounting app? Or should I create all my apps in the main project root? The way I've started doing it is creating child apps inside of their parent apps but some parent apps are so big that even this gets messy. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: I think this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862084/how-do-i-create-sub-applications-in-django

Answer (score 0):

If you have gone through Two Scoops of Django then you should probably check out Django Cookiecutter which has been created by the authors of this book.

Django Cookiecutter is an excellent boilerplate for starting a Django application both for personal use and for production.

They also have excellent documentation which will help you with the best practices for Python and Django coding.

Check out: [Django Cookiecutter Git Link](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the tastes of each developer. I split each funtionality in a separate app for example. I have never used child apps. Excepts when I work with Django Rest Framework. With Django Rest Framework I create a child app of each up for REST funtionality.