# Can I use a directory to contains a couples app directory?

Tags: python, django, project

Can I use a directory to contains a couples app directory? 
I mean, my project is very large, and there are many apps in my project.
such as apps about admin user, apps about normal user, apps about frontend, apps about ...

So, my project is very clutter, I want to use a group directory to wrap the related apps into it.

I don't know whether this idea is feasible. some friend can help me with this? is there should take care of some other things?

The snapshot red framework is a group apps. I want to group them, who can help me with this?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862084/how-do-i-create-sub-applications-in-django) answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that probably you are using one of the latest versions of Django.

In my case I like to create a folder called apps to keep the project more organized.

This is my project structure example:

[image]

and then I am doing this in the settings.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PARENT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, os.pardir))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PARENT_DIR, 'apps'))
```

[image]

So, I think you could do something similar creating multiple folders to organize your custom apps.

I hope it make sense.

Comment: I follow your method, but I get the issue <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392670/must-be-of-the-form-app-label-modelname-model-valueerror-invalid-model-re">there</a>, can you take a little time to have a look?

Comment: Hi, ok. I will take a look, for me is working. did you have any progress?

Comment: Hi @244boy, I have checked and is working , I didn't have the error that you have mentioned