# How to use apps with the same name in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps, django-2.0

I created a project say foo. And created an app named admin. But it causes an error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: admin”
```

So I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319562/5132337) and made changes as mentioned there. I marked the label as `foo.admin`.
I don't exactly know what the label is, but maybe this is the unique name given to an app to distinguish apps with the same name in case.
**So is that mean, everywhere I have to use `label` instead of `name`?**
But it causes another error.
`String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'`.
So I used the name in models as `foo.admin` in `ForeignKey` parameter. But the same error comes up. But the error persists.
I googled the error and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47392670/5132337). So I changed the `ForeignKey` parameter from `foo.admin` to `admin`. But in either case, I'm having this error.

So in short I want to ask

**How to use apps with the same name in the same django project, like Which files are need to be modified and what to write ForeignKey parameters etc.?**

(I'm using django 2.0)

Comment: have you tried to use a valid Python identifier (without dots) as a label? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label

Comment: I tried with `foo_admin` admin also. Then it is showing that 'foo_admin' app is not found something error.

Comment: You need to follow the solution in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319558/how-to-resolve-django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-application-labels/24319562#24319562). That let's you override the app label. To make your ForeignKeys work, you should only need to pick a label that doesn't contain dots.

Comment: I tried label as `siraj_admin` but still it didn't work.